# Huge lag and screen freezes changing the brightness on Ubuntu 20.04 using the hotkeys

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, laptop, brightness, dell-vostro

When I press FN+F4(brightness down) or FN+F5(brightness up) to change the brightness of my screen on my Dell Vostro 5480. It freezes my screen and it seams to "hold" the key and keep reducing the brightness till the maximum or minimum possible and then after a while it stops.
Why it happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/84453o/delayfreezecpu_spike_when_using_the_functionmedia/

It's just about commenting this line:

```
modifier_map Mod3 { Scroll_Lock };
```

on the following keyboard layout file for your language:
(br in my case):

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br
```

Comment: Works on my Dell Inspiron 7000 model running Ubuntu 20.04